# Astropy WCS transfromation matrix

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy

I am trying to create a custom WCS to transform pixel coordinates of an image into world coordinates.

Given an image with stars, I already have identified 2 stars, so I can match pixels (x,y) to (RA,DEC) for two points in the image.

What I would like now, is to create a custom WCS with the proper transformation matrix, so when I give any pixel coordinate it will return the corresponding RA and DEC.

I known astrometry.net does it, and writes a fits header with the appropriate transformation matrix.

My question is, how can I get to this transformation matrix and create my custom WCS object?

Thanks.

EDIT:
This is the code I'm trying:

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.wcs.utils import fit_wcs_from_points
import numpy as np
# I have the following stars identified in my image (andromeda):
#  (X, Y)       --> (RA in degrees, DEC in degrees) --> HIP_ID
#  (640, 555)   --> (17.43421495, 35.61993419)      --> 5447
#  (1076, 32)  --> (2.09777329, 29.08952671)        --> 607
#  (161, 903)  --> (30.9751282, 42.32944223)        --> 9640
#  (932, 327)  --> (9.83272908, 30.86056254)        --> 3092
stars = SkyCoord(ra=[17.43421495, 2.09777329, 30.9751282, 9.83272908], 
                 dec=[35.61993419, 29.08952671, 42.32944223, 30.86056254], 
                 unit=u.deg)
stars
pixels_x = np.array([640, 1076, 161, 932])
pixels_y = np.array([555, 32, 903, 327])
wcs = fit_wcs_from_points((pixels_x, pixels_y), stars); wcs
wcs.wcs_pix2world(np.array([[640]]),np.array([555]),0)
```

Why I don't even get the reference point correct?

Comment: Could you share some code with what you already have and your desired output?

Comment: Have you tried `fits_wcs_from_points`? You can pass it the x, y and ra, dec coordinates of some points as well as the transformation type, and it will determine the transformation parameters and construct a WCS

Comment: @Let'stry I have added some code, and Iguananaut thanks once again for your help, that function is indeed what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, the problem is the version of the Astropy library, see bug: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/10155.

If anyone faces this problem, make sure you are not using Astropy 4.0.1.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?  I'm sure you're right that this solved your problem, but it's not clear from your question that this was related to your problem in the first place.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the details of the problem, more than the description of the PR I linked above. But we tested it with some people from the Astropy Slack channel and one of them found the problem in this specific version, so just changing the version the code above, returns the right values for the reference points (which is the expected result).